# Android fragment shared element transition implementation

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, xamarin, android-transitions

I have an Android app that provides navigation through online folders (like Google Drive). I have implemented the folder navigation with fragments. The main activity has a toolbar and the remaining space is used for fragments. One fragment represents one folder. Subfolders and files are displayed using a `RecyclerView` and when a new folder is opened, the old fragment gets hidden and a new fragment for the opened folder is added.

Now i want to add animations to my application, specifically, for opening and closing of folders. When a folder in the list is clicked i want the background view of the clicked item  to expand to become the background of the new fragment. When back is pressed, the opposite should happen.

Here is a video i found of something similar to what i want to achieve: https://youtu.be/xvy7KUe492g

However in the video the clicked view expands over the toolbar, whereas i want the toolbar to remain visible.

Could you help me out by writing an example, or pointing me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This link is pretty clear and has many examples

http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal